# Testing numeric value of an element for 'If/then'

Tags: jasmine, protractor

### Protractor E2E Testing

**Scenario**

I need to be able to click on a value in a grid as long as that value is greater than 1.

If the condition is met, then click on the element to proceed to the next step.

If the condition fails, - *ideally*, try the value in the next column or failing that - a console message.

I understand that the initial element needs to be a variable....

```
var avail  = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='grd_Availability']/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]"));
```

If anyone could help with some broad brush-stroke advice and examples of doing this sort of thing, I'd be very grateful.
David

Comment: Did you try filter function? Use element.all and filter.

Comment: Hi Barney- no I've not tried that...I'll give it a go. Thanks